# Can't find the values of certain keys that are used as parameters while issuing post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script to scrape content from a [webpage](https://www.rentfaster.ca/bc/victoria/rentals/?l=4,54.9773,-112.766). When I navigate to the aforementioned link, I can see the total listing displayed as `Results (10080)`. This number varies each time I refresh the page.

I can generate the number of results using the script below. To do this, though, I need to copy the values of `l` and `area` from devtools and use them as parameters while issuing post requests.

For total listings:

```
url = 'https://www.rentfaster.ca/api/map.json'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
params = {
    'l': '4,54.9773,-112.766',
    'area': '59.68965038087162,-91.935921875,49.63882324278784,-133.596078125',
    'exclude': ''
}
res = requests.post(url,data=params,headers=headers)
print(res.json()['total'])
```

What I can't understand is how the values of `l` and `area` are generated, and how can I retrieve them using the script? To be specific, when I go for the ***city-wise*** listings, as in `Calgary, AB`, I also need to use values of `l` and `area` as parameters while sending post requests.

For city-wise listings:

```
url = 'https://www.rentfaster.ca/api/map.json'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
params = {
    'l': '13,51.0452,-114.0764',
    'area': '51.058053440451424,-114.0356853316207,51.03236736163589,-114.11705282429648',
    'e': 'zoom_changed',
    'exclude': ''
}
res = requests.post(url,data=params,headers=headers)
print(res.json())
```

> Question: How can I find the values of `l` and `area` that are used as parameters while issuing post requests?

Comment: [so] is not a site for asking reverse engineering questions but rather programming questions, figuring out how a third party site's internal API works is not on-topic. See: [Are questions about reverse engineering internal APIs of a website on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426819/are-questions-about-reverse-engineering-internal-apis-of-a-website-on-topic) If it helps you in any way the first part of that `l` parameter is linked to the zoom level of the map while the other two seems to be related to the co-ordinates.

Comment: If I understand the answer to your linked question correctly, this is the gist portion: `questions asking for reverse engineering an entire service or platform (like an API) are too broad, so those can be closed as needing focus, similar to asking how to build a "Facebook killer"` your accepted answer refers to. However, this has nothing to do with the question I've posed here. Thanks @Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: The part you've quoted from that answer starts with an "_Alternatively_" meaning it is just _one part_ of that answer. See the part just before that: "_These questions are no different than someone asking for help with debugging proprietary code and refusing to share it._" (And read the actual question to understand what this refers to). That API expects certain values in the request body as you mention, you have no clue what they are, the API doesn't have any public documentation either. How do you expect people here to answer this?

Comment: I think the answer can be derived using logic on the payload that was given for the successful call, I left an answer. Please be mindful of my disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right approach:

```py
# found empirically by checking area coords it looks like it's the half point + constant value 0.31 etc
DELTA_LAT = 0.31306318817026835 + (59.68965038087162 - 49.63882324278784 / 2)
# found same way
DELTA_LON = (133.596078125 - 91.935921875) /2
lat = input()
lon = input()

l = f'4,{lat},{lon}'
area = f'{lat+DELTA_LAT},{lon+DELTA_LON},{lat-DELTA_LAT},{lon-DELTA_LON}'
```

Using logic it seems that:

- L is (zoom level, centre latitude, centre longitude)
- AREA is the coordinate box of (centre latitude - zoom value, centre longitude - zoom value, centre latitude + zoom value, centre longitude + zoom value)

i.e. you can find zoom value by checking manually, i.e. it seems like -112.766 - (41.66015625 / 2) = 133.59 etc  So zoom value for longitude (at zoom level 4) seems to be (41.66015625 / 2). The same seems to apply to latitude, this should be verified manually.

Disclaimer: I am simply applying logic to the info you posted and encourage you to check T&Cs before attempting to scrape or perform automation on any website you do not own!